# Swift App "freezes" when trying to share content via mail or message

Tags: swift

when trying to share content via Mail or Message (using UIActivityViewController), the Screen "freezes" when trying to dismiss the Mail or Message View after send or cancel action.

The console does not show anything.
However it seems that the view of my initial ViewController keeps stuck in a loop calling layoutSubviews().

[Screenshot of frozen screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRWbx.jpg)

Here's my function which presents the UIActivityViewController:

```
func displayShareSheet(shareContent:String) {
    self.service.AnalyticsActionShareFeedback()

    let shareView = UIView(frame: self.view.bounds)
    let bgImageView = UIImageView(frame: shareView.bounds)
    bgImageView.image = self.backgroundImage.image
    bgImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    shareView.addSubview(bgImageView)

    let viewCopy = UIImageView(image: UIImage(view: view))
    shareView.addSubview(viewCopy)
    let shareImage = UIImage(view: shareView)
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [shareContent as NSString, shareImage as UIImage], applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = {(act, success, a, error) in
        print("Activity dismissed")
    }
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [.addToReadingList, .airDrop, .assignToContact, .openInIBooks, .postToFacebook, .postToTwitter, .postToVimeo, .postToWeibo, .postToFlickr, .saveToCameraRoll]
    let subject = "Received Feedback via MyFeedback"
    activityViewController.setValue(subject, forKey: "Subject")
    if let popoverController = activityViewController.popoverPresentationController {
        popoverController.sourceView = self.view
        popoverController.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
        popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = []
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: {
            print("Activity shown")
        })
    }

}
```

Any ideas?
EDIT:
Screenshot when pausing execution:
[Screenshot when pausing execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOQw7.jpg)

Comment: The code you've provided works fine. Since you're using a `UIImage` extension which you did not include in your example, I replaced those images with an asset. Also, I've removed `self.service.AnalyticsActionShareFeedback()`, since it's not present in your code either. My suspicion is that you should search for the problem either in those functions or in another part of your code. If you pause the execution when the screen freezes, does it halt on a line?

Comment: @the4kman thanks for your comment! I removed `self.service.AnalyticsActionShareFeedback()`and also replaced those images with an asset, but same the still issue. When pausing the execution it stops at the line in absove's screenshot